# Do I need direct-burial rated CAT5e for exterior wall contact?

Tags: cabling

I need to make some CAT5e cable runs (50-100') along the top edge of an exterior brick fence. Even though it's not buried, it'll probably be in frequent long contact with stuff that hangs out in the brick (e.g. water, insects, whatever), plus there's some weeds that like to grow on this particular fence. Do I need direct-burial rated cable because of the water / plant contact or can I just use exterior but non-burial cable? (I already own the latter)

Comment: OSP (Outside Plant) cabling is a specialty best left to the experts because there are dangers that put you into legal and financial jeopardy. You need proper grounding, bonding, and lightning protection, and outside cabling has restrictions coming inside, e.g. length. This really is not something you want to do yourself.

Comment: This question would be best on a help section where people can interact and provide opinions and recommendations, etc. My advice would be to run fiber optic if you have to run outdoor cable at all. Copper cable run outside is basically an antenna for electromagnetic surges and interference. It requires very specific solutions for grounding and shielding. As for cable specifically for outdoor use, you will need UV resistant cabling, and possibly freeze resistant cabling if it for use in an environment where it goes below freezing temperatures regularly.

Comment: Direct burial cable may not be suitable for aerial use. You'll want something designed to withstand extended UV (sun) exposure. Interior (patch, riser, plenum, etc.) will not survive being in the sun.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer If a cable is labelled "for outdoor use" (my assumption, which might be wrong, has always been that that meant UV-resistance), can it probably also withstand freezing temperatures or is that kind of a crap shoot if it doesn't explicitly say it?

Comment: @Ricky That pretty much answers my question, if you want to post it as an answer. Makes sense that it wouldn't be designed to do well in the sun if it was supposed to go underground. Thank you.

Comment: @RonMaupin For this question, I'm not interested in anything except what the ratings (or at least the direct-burial qualifier) on CAT5 cabling entail wrt. exposure.

Comment: Your installer can answer that for you. If you install something yourself, and a spike from lightning causes a fire in your business where someone gets hurt, you can be held both civilly and criminally liable. If you need to ask this question, you are not qualified to install it, and you place yourself at risk.

Comment: @RonMaupin Since this question is about cable ratings, anything else sounds like a good topic for chat. Ricky gave me the answer I needed, thanks for your help.

Comment: I just commented; I did not answer.

Comment: @JasonC, not all outdoor rated is UV resistant (though it seems to be many are, just check the details) and not all is rated for cold weather (about 50/50 and they mention it). Freeze resistant cable actually has a gel in it that prevents water entry to prevent ice build up which would damage the conductors and eventually the sheath. Then there is shielded which again may or may not be UV resistant or gel filled. I don't think I have ever seen gel filled shielded. Shielded cable requires specific grounding implementation and should be avoided in most cases. Fiber is usually easier.